# Getting Text File data after Instr is true and splitting

Tags: excel, vba, text-files

I attached a copy of a sample text file. I am have a code that finds the storeID and Date which are on the first line (StoreID = 101190 and Date is = 112421). In a cell on the worksheet I have the storeID and Date combined. I have the code below that I was able to put together but that gets me to the end of the line. I would like to get from the date cell value to "99 END OF DAY". I want lines 12 and 13A to be split as each value represents a payment. Then Disposal Fee line and safety Inspection line to be split as well. How can I implement this? Any help would be appreciated. I put a google drive link to a File sample that contains 3 dates. Usually the file contains all the Data from couple of years back so it is a long file.

```
 Sub GetDailySales()
  todaysdate = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value
  todaysdate2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value & Format(todaysdate, "mmddyy")


sFile = "C:\Users\axela\Desktop\FileSample.txt"
 
Dim objFSO As Object
Dim objTextFile As Object
Dim lngCount As Long, i As Long
Dim FileNum As Integer
Dim DataLine As String
Dim strFound As String
Dim bFound As Boolean
Dim vLine As Variant
        Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(sFile, ForReading, -1)
    
Do While Not objTextFile.AtEndOfStream
        lngCount = lngCount + 1    'increment a counter'
         ' read in data 1 line at a time'
         DataLine = objTextFile.ReadLine
        If InStr(1, DataLine, todaysdate2) > 0 Then    'the string is found'
            bFound = True    'set a boolean value to true'
            Exit Do    'and stop the loop'
        End If
    Loop
     
    If bFound = True Then    'The text string was found'
        'Read through the file line by line to the line after the found line'
    
        For i = 1 To lngCount
        Do While Not objTextFile.AtEndOfStream
            strFound = objTextFile.ReadLine
            strFound = Trim(strFound)
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = strFound

       Loop
        Next i
       
        objTextFile.Close    'close the file'
        Set objFSO = Nothing
        Set objTextFile = Nothing
    Else    'The text was not found'
    FileSearch = "Not found" 'tell the user'
End If
Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Result needed:
Row that starts with 12 and 13a split each number value so

```
12 1707.97152211    142.16     73.54    299.67   1071.52     73.54      0.00      0.0017:01     47.54      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00X1      0.00      0.00
13A    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   6  26    0.00   1687.69   1729.69   97.35    0.00    0.00   75.63    0.00   0  12  20  26   1687.69

SAFETY INSPECTION 63.00 9
DISPOSAL FEE 65.00 26
```

If not possible then just put the data into the worksheet and I will use powerquery to handle the rest. I am just having issues grabbing the data from the StoreID and Date to 99 END OF DAY. I need each day by it self based on the sheets cell value.

Comment: Can you show what you want as a result?

Comment: @norie I updated the first post with results needed if possible. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, try the next code:

```
Sub extractDatafromTextFile()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, txtFileName As String, lastR As Long, i As Long, j As Long
  Dim arrTxt, arrPay1, arrPay2, arrSI, arrDF, SI As Long, val1 As Double
  Const todaysdate2 As String = "101190112421" 'take it from your worksheet
  
  Set sh = 'ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
  txtFileName = "C:\Users\Fane Branesti\Downloads\FileSample.txt"
  arrTxt = Split(CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(txtFileName, 1).ReadAll, vbCrLf)
  
  For i = 0 To UBound(arrTxt)
      If InStr(arrTxt(i), todaysdate2) > 0 Then
         Do While InStr(arrTxt(i + j), "END OF DAY") = 0
            j = j + 1
            If left(arrTxt(i + j), 3) = "12 " Then
                arrPay1 = Split(WorksheetFunction.Trim(arrTxt(i + j)), " ")
            End If
            If left(arrTxt(i + j), 4) = "13A " Then
                arrPay2 = Split(WorksheetFunction.Trim(arrTxt(i + j)), " ")
            End If
            If InStr(arrTxt(i + j), "SAFETY INSPECTION") > 0 Then
                SI = InStr(arrTxt(i + j), "SAFETY INSPECTION")
                arrSI = Split(WorksheetFunction.Trim(left(arrTxt(i + j), SI - 1)), " ")
                val1 = arrSI(1):
                arrSI(0) = "SAFETY INSPECTION": arrSI(1) = arrSI(2): arrSI(2) = val1
            End If
            If InStr(arrTxt(i + j), "DISPOSAL FEE") > 0 Then
                SI = InStr(arrTxt(i + j), "DISPOSAL FEE")
                arrDF = Split(WorksheetFunction.Trim(left(arrTxt(i + j), SI - 1)), " ")
                val1 = arrDF(1):
                arrDF(0) = "DISPOSAL FEE": arrDF(1) = arrDF(2): arrDF(2) = val1
            End If
         Loop
      End If
  Next i
  lastR = sh.Range("A" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
  sh.Range("A" & lastR + 1).Resize(1, UBound(arrPay1) + 1).value = arrPay1
  sh.Range("A" & lastR + 2).Resize(1, UBound(arrPay2) + 1).value = arrPay2
  sh.Range("A" & lastR + 3).Resize(1, UBound(arrSI) + 1).value = arrSI
  sh.Range("A" & lastR + 4).Resize(1, UBound(arrDF) + 1).value = arrDF
  MsgBox "Ready..."
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you this works great I was wondering if I can get all the data from the Row that starts with 12 all the way down to 99 End of Day. As I need to add a bunch of more items like the Disposal Fee and Safety Inspection. Sometimes between the first row their is added lines I do not need. So after the First StoreID and Date line start copying from the row that starts with 12 all the way down to 99 End of day. Or maybe elaborate please on how I can add extra items like "AIR FILTER for example". I am new so I will be trying to go one by one to understand what is going on. Thank you again

Comment: I was able to add more items just looking through the code and what not. I am just more familiar with power query if possible to do the extraction as well. I know that was not the original question but just so I can learn more and how its possibly could be done in future projects without asking again. Thanks again

Comment: Disregard my comments I went ahead and went over the code you provided and have adjusted it to my needs. I cannot thank you enough.

Comment: Quick question, sometimes “Safety inspection” is not there. If no services are done it is usually missing the line from the text file. So it’s throwing an error, how can I go about checking if its not empty with an array?

Comment: 'If Not arrSI = "" Then' drop its value. And, in order to avoid an empty row when missing you should use 'lastR = lasrR + 1' in front of each row to drop arrays content. I left home for two days and no acces to any computer...

Comment: I tried the following but I get a Type Mismatch Error..   If Not arrSI = "" Then
                sh.Range("B" & lastR + 1).Resize(1, 1).Value = arrSI(2)
               End If

Comment: On the first line? It shouldn't and the second line should not be run... Please, try 'If arrSI <> "" then'...

Comment: On the second line correct after the IF so where sh.range starts

Comment: I added a space between the quotes and arrSI worked for empty but I have another array that I added below it that is also throwing an error even though it does have value. That is throwing the error on the first line. Also if arrSI does have a value and its not empty it throws an error on the first line as well

Comment: What you say does not make sense, sorry... I cannot test anything in the next two days.